# Visual c# Form Controls Overlaps/Layering

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there anyway to control what controls (buttons, group boxes, ectect) will overlap others? For example...

I add a button1 to the form, then button2. But, (for some reason) I want button1 to overlap button2 if they were to ever overlap.

I have googled this and found nothing, and if I found something chances it would bring me here. I know this is probably easy to do anyways.

Thanks for your help and time.

Im trying to avoid a copy paste nightmare via adding buttons. And I'm new to Visual c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Visual Studio windows form designer, you can right click GUI elements and select either *Bring to front* or *Send to back*. Or you can also use the Format menu entries:
[image]

Another option would be to do it by code; assuming you have two buttons (called buttonOK and button Cancel) you can control which goes above by giving it a higher TabIndex.

```
buttonOK.TabIndex = 0;
buttonCancel.TabIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I have low rep so I can't do anything, but ty ty ty ty ty over and over. =D

Comment: I think you can mark the answer as accepted after some time, but no problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your controls can overlap if they're too close. There's nothing stopping you from adding a control over another one.